# FaceBook user work position name parsing issue

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am having issues when trying to get a work position name on a facebook graph. What I have tried (in json):

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJK

    {
    "id":"123456789",
    "name":"me me",
    "work": [
    {
    "position": {
    "id":"987654321",
    "name":"administrator"
            }
    }
    ]
    }
```

Here, I am attempting to use "user_work_history", and it's pemission seems to have been authorized.

```
    echo json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$useid))->work->position->name
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well. The short answer is that the work object is an array of objects, so you'll need to access the appropriate array element. The following should do the trick:

```
    echo json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$useid))->work[0]->position->name
```

The longer answer includes some style nitpicks - personally I'd break up that code into at least two lines, mainly for readability, and I generally prefer to get an assoc array from json_decode rather than an object, but ofc either way works. Here's an approximation of how I'd rewrite this (ignoring for the moment that you're not using the PHP SDK, which you probably should be). Not necessarily best practices (I don't claim to be an authority :p) but, imho, much easier to quickly read, understand, debug, and adjust:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $user_id);
$user = json_decode($json, true);
$job_title = $user['work'][0]['position']['name'];
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it ;) Good answer, and I also recommend decoding the json into an array instead of an object, as shown in the last code block.

Comment: @user1769752 - Which way isn't working (obj or array?), and in what way is it not working?

Comment: i'm still happy to help if you haven't solved your problem yet, i just need more to go on than "it didn't work."